# Voltage of IRF150M MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

My dad is working on a power supply device and happen to come across a MOSFET,  I apologize but I do not have much knowledge of electronics, which is labelled IRF150M. He knows the voltage and current rating of IRF150N which is 100V and 42A - as far as I remember. He does not understand English so he asked me to search the internet, but I could not find any datasheet related to IRF150M. Although, from a little guessing I told him that its voltage rating will also be 100V and current 38A to 42A, but he said that its voltage cannot be 100V based on a test he did. Can anyone tell me the voltage and current rating of IRF150M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a pretty old device. 
Here is the datasheet i was able to find: http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/134/283458_DS.pdf

The rated *V<sub>ds</sub>* is, as you stated, 100V.